# How to change color and font of UITextField Placeholder in Xamarin for iOS7

Tags: ios7, xamarin

```
using(UIFont font=StyleHelper.Fonts.HelveticaNeueLTDMC_18
using(UIColor color=UIColor.Clear.FromHex(0xc7c7c7))
{
    color.SetFill ();

    base.DrawString (this.Placeholder, rect, font);

}
```

I am using above code but it is not working.

Comment: Xamarin coding is different than xcode-5?

Comment: You can use the attributedPlaceholder property.

Take a look here: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField.AttributedPlaceholder

Comment: Wow thanks Cray. Simple solution that i almost missed. You should make it an answer!

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 9):

As seen on the iOS-API documentation for [MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField.AttributedPlaceholder](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P:MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField.AttributedPlaceholder), you can clearly see:

```
myLogin.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString (
    "Enter your credentials",
    font: UIFont.FromName ("HoeflerText-Regular", 24.0f),
    foregroundColor: UIColor.Red,
    strokeWidth: 4 
);
```